# Как создать recommend system на основании обратной связи от пользователя?

Tags: машинное-обучение

Задача: У меня есть список шаблонов емейлов, скажем их 100 штук.
Эти емейлы мы предлагаем пользователю. В свою очередь, он может выбрать один шаблон и отправить своему клиенту. В клиента тоже есть ряд признаков (например, город, стать, доход и т. д... )

Если клиент отвечает на шаблон, то мы говорим, что шаблон достиг цели. Если нет - не достиг.

Я хочу создать рекомендательный алгоритм, который будет рекомендовать шаблон на основании обратной связи от клиента (считаем что обратная связь позитивная, если клиент открыл емейл) и профиля клиента по ряду признаков, т. е. чем больше таких же клиентов отвечают на шаблон, тем более он популярный для данной группы клиентов.

Вот пример данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`email_template_id` - id отправленного емейла в БД

`Answered?` - ответил ли клиент на емейл или нет

Пот пример выходных данных
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Где `Recommended emails` - рекомендованый список емейлов в подядке приоритета

Какие алгоритмы ML помогут достичь этой цели?
Буду благодарен за любые рекомендации

Спасибо

Comment: Приведите примеры входных/выходных данных

Comment: @dIm0n добавил пример данных